# How to change the root of a radial tree in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I'm having a problem with my Radial tree in D3.js

I would like to put the selected node (on click) in the center of the radial tree and have the whole tree readapt to this new setting. In my update function I can set the root to the selected node:

```
root = source;
```

However this only shows the selected node and children, but I would like to have the parent (and its children) on top of the selected node, and the children of the selected node on the bottom of it.

What I have tried is to remove the selected node from the array of children of the parent. Then pushing this changed parent as a child of the selected node, however this gives recursion errors.

```
var index = source.parent.children.indexOf(source);
source.parent.children.splice(0, 1);
source.parent.parent = source;
source.children.push(source.parent);
```

Full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Anas77/mugc0sx4/)

I would appreciate any help or indication at all.

Thank you

Comment: The approach you've tried is good, it must be a problem in your function. Can you share the code of the function you've tried?

Comment: I've added the code I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Do you want to have only the parent of the selected node in your tree, or also the grand-parent, etc., up to the original root?

Comment: Ideally the grand-parents etc as well. The final goal of the visualization is to have the selected node in the center of the screen, in the south part of the radial tree would be all the children of the selected node and on the north part would be the parent/grand parents... But don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive function taking care of the rearrangement:

```
function makeRoot(source) {
   if (!source.parent) return; //nothing to do if source is already root

   makeRoot(source.parent); //flip the higher branches recursively so that the parent becomes root of the tree 

   var index = source.parent.children.indexOf(source);
   source.parent.children.splice(index, 1);  //corrected here: you need to remove the right element from the children list
   source.parent.parent = source;
   source.children.push(source.parent);
   delete source.parent; //added: now that the original parent is linked, make source the root of the tree
}
```

I'm not sure how to force the children of the original node to be drawn to the south and the rest to the north. A first thing to do would be to *know* on which side each node must be (this is easy: by default all nodes are "north", then visit the subtree from `source`, before the call to `makeRoot`, and tell them to be "south"). But after that, I'm not familiar enough with the tree layout from d3 to enforce the "north/south" constraint.

---

**update** for the north-south orientation, you can try the following:

- keep a pointer `oldParent=source.parent` to the original parent of the selected node
- once the layout is done, and before updating the svg, compute `offsetX= 90- oldParent.x` (the difference between the parent position and the north axis -- NB: I'm not sure about north axis being 90°, but it should be one of 0, 90, 180 or 270.. just try them all ;) )
- shift all nodes around by an amount of `offsetX` (keeping angles between 0 and 359):

  ```
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x = (d.x + offsetX) % 360;
  });
  ```
- then you can update the svg: the whole tree should be rotated so that the  original parent points north ... which should be enough to get the visual effect you wanted.

---

**update #2** Another way to make the north-south alignment.

See Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qo4w0ktn/4/

The idea is to compute the angle of the left-most and right-most leaf among the original children, and rotate the whole diagram until the average of these two angles points south. It means you need to keep track of the "original" children in the tree, this is done with my `d.real_children` property. Functions `leftmostLeaf` and `rightmostLeaf` are straightforward (see the fiddle).

```
  function rotateSouth(source, nodes) {
    var lx = leftmostLeaf(source);
    var rx = rightmostLeaf(source);

    if (lx>rx) rx += 360; //this happens if the interval overlap angle 0

    var offsetX= 180- (lx+rx)/2; //the median point (=(lx+rx)/2) should be pushed south (=180)

    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      d.x = (d.x + offsetX) % 360; //rotate every node by the same offset
    });  
  }
```

Comment: Great, thank you D3 genius it worked !
For the last part, about rotating the whole tree, could you give me some hints on that ?

Comment: Here's a tentative update on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qo4w0ktn/2/ .... I've added a "parity" feature in makeRoot to have the ancestor's tree go alternatively left and right (and on average, go rather straight), but the result is not as nice as expected. I'll try some more fiddling

Comment: @AnasHelalouch see my second update. I think this answers your original question, what remains is to fix the line drawing (links that have been reversed are drawn backwards), but the overall structure should be fine.

Comment: Thank you kindly Laurent, that did it.